# Find all integer solutions...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all integer solutions of $a^3 + 2b^3 = 4c^3$.

Thanks!

PS: Also, can you give me some general ideas on approaching these kinds of problems? And a good book recommendation on elementary number theory?

Comment: Reducing mod $9$ also works.

Comment: As for the question itself; what are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Where did you find this problem? Without any context it is hard to give a useful answer.

Comment: I searched for [tag:elementary-number-theory] and [tag:book-recommendation] here and got $74$ [results](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Belementary-number-theory%5D+and+%5Bbook-recommendation%5D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, $a^3+2b^3=4c^3$

We wonder whether or not $a$ is even.  (*Try to explain why*)

> We notice then that $a^3=4c^3-2b^3$ is the difference of two even numbers and so $a^3$ is even.  It follows that $a$ is even.  (*To see this, consider the contrapositive*)

So, given that $a$ is even we see that $a$ can be rewritten as $a=2d$ for some integer $d$ and the original equation can be rewritten as $(2d)^3+2b^3=4c^3$ or as $8d^3+2b^3=4c^3$.

Dividing everything by two we have $4d^3+b^3=2c^3$

We wonder whether or not $b$ is even.

> The same logic as before applies, $b^3=2c^3-4d^3$ is the difference of two even numbers.

So, given that $b$ is even we apply the same logic and see the original equation can be rewritten as $4d^3+8e^3=2c^3$ and dividing by two we have $2d^3+4e^3=c^3$

> We continue the process indefinitely realizing that $a=2d=4g=8j=\dots$ and that $a$ is divisible by every power of $2$.  There is only one finite number for which this is possible and that is zero itself.  The same is true for the other values.

$~$

> So the only solution to the equation is $(a,b,c)=(0,0,0)$

Comment: This is also all rational solution to the equation.

Comment: Well, yes.  To see that, it suffices to note that any rational solution would otherwise convert to an integer solution by clearing the common denominator.

Comment: Thank you very much. And some book recommendations for elementary number theory?